# error cannot access zza after adding firestore

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle, google-cloud-firestore

I have added Firestore in my gradle and when I sync its syncs correctly but when I run the project I got this error.

```
error: cannot access zza class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza not found
```

here is my gradle file dependencies

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0'
compile 'com.github.florent37:singledateandtimepicker:1.2.2'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.7.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.7.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'
compile 'com.chabbal:slidingdotsplash:1.0.2'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0'
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please change this lines of code:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
```

to

```
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1' //(Must be commented)
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
```

Also be sure to use:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1'
```

In your `build.gradle` (Project) file.

Comment: I have updated all gradle files now i am getting this error ------- class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found

Comment: Have you also added `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the end of your file, where `dependencies` end?

Comment: Now getting this error .....   All firebase libraries must be either above or below 14.0.0

Comment: It means that in your dependencies exist another firebase dependency with a lower version. Are you sure you have updated all firebase correctly? If you are not sure, please share you file again, with the changes included.

Comment: Please see [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) all correct versions. Does it work now?

Comment: There is no other Firebase library in dependency just firestore:16.0.0  I am getting the above error when I add "apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'" at the bottom

Comment: Then, is there any atoher google play service dependencies that it has not the last versions `15.0.1`? Can share the file again?

Comment: Yes this one..... com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1. ---  when I update this to 15 I got this error -----Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1.

Comment: Try to make **all** `15.0.0`, what is happening?

Comment: Getting same error --- Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.0.----

Comment: Put back `15.0.1` and remove that `com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1`. Use only the desired ones (maps, auth and so on), works this way?

Comment: Ahh its done... thanks... I jut need to comment that line.... and i was stuck in that from last day..... Thanks Alex

Answer (score 0):

**Firebase is now distributing their packages with independent version numbers, ensure all packages on build.gradle are the latest one**

Update All google  dependencies to latest one,for example in your question need to update below lines,**Also change `complie` with `implementation`**

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0'
```